# What's wrong with my approach - reciprocal integral

Tags: calculus, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I want to integrate $\int \frac{1}{2x}dx$

The way I would solve it: $$\frac{1}{a}f(ax + b)$$ where $$f(x) = \ln x$$ 
**My answer** $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2x) + k$

The correct way seems to be to factor out $\frac{1}{2}$ from the initial integral, leaving $\int \frac{1}{x}$. The **correct answer** $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x) + k$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $lnx$ is not linear so $aln(x)=ln(ax)$ is not usually a true statement.

Comment: It's due to your constant of integration. To make the integrals equal, use the fact that $\ln(2x) = \ln(2) + \ln(x)$ and hence $1/2 \ln(2) + k = c$ where $k$ is your integration constant and $c$ is the other approaches integration constant. This has been asked before, so search the MSE site for a better explanation if you need.

Comment: @Mattos What should I search for (concept/topic) ? It's just really hard when you don't know what to search for.

Comment: @Mari0 Yeah, the search function isn't great due to the LaTeX typeset I think. I tried to find it before for you but couldn't. Searching for problems dealing with the integral of $1/x$ is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $I=\int \frac {1}{2x} dx$.

Therefore, $$\begin {align} & I =\int \frac {1}{2x} dx \\ & =\int \frac {1}{2}\cdot \frac {2}{2x} dx \\ & =\frac {1}{2}\cdot \int  \frac {1}{2x} d(2x) \\ & =\frac {1}{2}  \ln (2x) + k\end{align}$$

So you see that the integration is totally correct. There is no flaw in it. However the integration constant  $k $ will make the difference and give the correct value as predicted by the other answer in case of a definite  integral.

Answer (score 1):

You are not wrong; however, your answer is just not simplified.

To check that your answer is correct, differentiate both your answer and the "correct" answer:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{1}{2} ln(2x) + k) = \frac{1}{2x}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{1}{2} ln(x) + k) = \frac{1}{2x}$$

To simplify:

$\frac{1}{2} ln(2x) + k = \frac{1}{2} (ln(x) + ln(2)) + k$
$=> \frac{1}{2} ln(x) + \frac{1}{2} ln(2) + k = \frac{1}{2} ln(x) + (\frac{1}{2} ln(2) + k)$

> $(\frac{1}{2} ln(2) + k)$ is another constant, so let's just call that C.

$=> \frac{1}{2} ln(2x) + k = \frac{1}{2} ln(x) + C$

C and k are just constants and do not affect the rate of change of the function; therefore, it doesn't matter what constant you add at the end of your equation as long as it is indeed constant.